# Display idref in XSLT from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to display the information within the idref quotations in a table this is how it is displayed in my XML.

```
 <state id="illinois">
      <scode>IL</scode>
      <sname>Illinois</sname>
      <capital idref="springfieldi"/>
      <citiesin idref="springfieldi"/>
      <citiesin idref="bloomington"/>
      <citiesin idref="chicago"/>
      <citiesin idref="peoria"/>
      <nickname>Prairie  State</nickname>
      <population>12128370</population>
    </state>
```

So far I have gotten the tabel to display the other elements. Here is my XSL code.

```
<table border="2">
            <tr bgcolor="grey">
                <th style="width:40px">ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Capital</th>
                <th>Cities</th>
                <th>Nickname</th>
                <th>Population</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="geography/state">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="scode" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="sname" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="capital" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="citiesin" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="nickname" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="population" /></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
```

When I do this the columns for capital and cities are blank. Also, since there are multiple elements each with a attribute. How would I display each of thos attributes? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capital` and `citiesin` are the **elements** in your input, but the value you want to output is in their `idref` **attribute**, so you must use:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="capital/@idref" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="citiesin/@idref" /></td>
```

In order to display all the `citiesin/@idref` values while using XSLT 1.0 you have to use a `for-each` loop:

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="capital">
        <xsl:value-of select="@idref"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

With XSLT 2.0 this is not necessary, as `<xsl:value-of select="citiesin/@idref" />` will already return a sequence containing all the values.

Comment: Since there are multiple elements each with a attribute. How would I display each of thos attributes?